# Push window to beginning, not to the end of stack when I press fullscreen

Tags: macos, spaces

Is it possible to push window to beginning, not to the end of stack when I press fullscreen?

For example, I have tree windows (or spaces) maximized

[image: spaces]

When I press "fullscreen" button I want new window to appear to the right of "Desktop" (left) space, not after all other spaces. Can I do this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In System Preferences > Mission Control, if you check the box for "Automatically rearrange spaces based on most recent use," then switching a window to fullscreen mode will place it to the right of the desktop space instead of at the end.